# Deserializing Json string into a nested object using gson gives null values for innermost fields in Java

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

I am using Gson builder to deserialize json string to my object. I have an object which contains a list, that list contains primitive fields as well as complex objects. After deserialization primitive fields get populated but all the complex fields come as null. Here is my JSON string:

```
{
    "branchCode": "000",
    "debitAccountName": "qwerty",
    "debitBankId": "12",
    "paymentInst": [
        {
            "amountPriority": "PC",
            "bankBranchCode": "444",
            "counterParty": {
                "beneficiaryCode": "xyz"
            },
            "creditAccNo": "998877",
            "debitCurrencyCode": "USD",
            "paymentAmount": 100,
            "MiscDetail": {
                "charge": "OUR",
                "debitCode": "000",
                "invoiceAmount": 120
            },
            "Product": {
                "productCode": "IFT"
            }
        }
    ],
    "totalUnitAmount": 100.00
}
```

When object is created, the MiscDetails, counterParty and product fields are null, rest are set fine. All the classes are non-abstract.

Comment: Do you have any modifications done on the POJO level ?

Comment: its not actually a pojo class, its a domain object entity with my JPA column mapping given by @column.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found my own answer. I didn't notice initially but i was using the `transient` keyword for the fields which were not getting populated.
By definition also `transient` means can't be serialized.

Comment: Going forward, you can try to post the same class in the questions to provide a better picture. If it's feasible for you ofcourse.